# executing uninstall string with powershell

Tags: windows, powershell

I am trying to make a Powershell script for uninstalling software.

Here is the code:

```
$software = Read-Host "Software you want to remove"
$paths = 'HKLM:\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Uninstall', 'HKLM:\SOFTWARE\Wow6432Node\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Uninstall'
Get-ChildItem $paths |
    Where-Object{ $_.GetValue('DisplayName') -match "$software" } |
    ForEach-Object{
        $uninstallString = $_.GetValue('UninstallString') + ' /quiet /norestart'
        Write-Host $uninstallString
        & "C:\Windows\SYSTEM32\cmd.exe" /c $uninstallString
    }
```

it works good for uninstall strings like

```
MsiExec.exe /X{C22F57FC-4B20-3354-8626-382E3C710B38} /quiet /norestart
```

But if I want to uninstall something like **winrar** which have uninstall strings like

```
C:\Program Files\WinRAR\uninstall.exe
```

I get the following error

```
cmd.exe : 'C:\Program' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
```

any idea please how to get this script working

Regards

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that you're *unconditionally* appending `/quiet /norestart`.

The solution is to test if the uninstall string *as a whole* refers to an executable file:

```
$isExeOnly = Test-Path -ErrorAction Ignore -LiteralPath $uninstallString
```

<sup>Note: `-ErrorAction Ignore` ignores `illegal characters in path` errors that occur when a string with *embedded `"`* chars. is passed.</sup>

Based on that, you can decide how you want to handle such executables:

- If the whole string *is* just an executable path and you simply want to execute it *without arguments* in that case (but you still want to append the desired options if the whole string is a *command line*, i.e. an executable *with arguments*):

```
$uninstallString = $_.GetValue('UninstallString')
$isExeOnly = Test-Path -ErrorAction Ignore -LiteralPath $uninstallString
if (-not $isExeOnly) { $uninstallString += ' /quiet /norestart' }
```

- If you do want to *unconditionally* pass options `/quiet /norestart` - even when the whole string is just an executable path - do the following, though note that the target executable may refuse to execute the resulting command line it doesn't understand these options:

```
$uninstallString = $_.GetValue('UninstallString')
$isExeOnly = Test-Path -ErrorAction Ignore -LiteralPath $uninstallString
if ($isExeOnly) { $uninstallString = "`"$uninstallString`"" } 
$uninstallString += ' /quiet /norestart'
```

The alternative is to *special-case the arguments* (options) to pass *based on the executable file name* (`Split-Path -Leaf $uninstallString`), but that is obviously cumbersome and impossible to do comprehensively.

Then pass the resulting string to `cmd /c` for execution:

```
cmd /c $uninstallString
```

Note:

- This is the appropriate thing to do, because such uninstall strings are written for `cmd.exe` or no-shell invocations, whereas PowerShell's different syntax rules could break the invocation; see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/68382753/45375) for more information.

Comment: I'm reading the problem as being about the path having a space and is not escaped correctly, how would adding additional arguments resolve that issue?

Comment: @NiKiZe, the premise of the question is the desire to pass additional arguments. The problem is that uninstall strings can situationally refer either to an unquoted _executable name or path only_ or to an entire _command line_ (executable _plus arguments_, which invariably involves spaces). The presence of spaces makes the value ambiguous, and you need to test which case applies: If the entire string is an executable path only that happens to contain spaces, it needs to be wrapped in `"..."` in order to be able to append arguments.

Answer (score 1):

Uninstall-package works with msi installs.

For non-msi installs:

You'd have to find out the silent uninstall options for winrar.  It might be '/S'.  (A quick google says it is.) (if you're lucky, there's a 'quietuninstallstring')

```
get-package *winrar* | % { & $_.metadata['uninstallstring'] /S }
```

Sometimes you have to get rid of literal double quotes:

```
get-package *winrar* | % { & ($_.metadata['uninstallstring'] -replace '"') /S }
```

Here's an attempt of a general answer for non-msi installs where part of the uninstallstring or quietuninstallstring may or may not be in double-quotes:

```
$uninstall = get-package whatever | % { $_.metadata['uninstallstring'] }
# match quoted words or words
$prog, $myargs = $uninstall | select-string '("[^"]*"|\S)+' -AllMatches | 
  % matches | % value
$prog = $prog -replace '"',$null
$myargs += '/S'  # whatever silent uninstall option
& $prog $myargs
```

Alternative approach running uninstallstring with "cmd /c".  Plus it waits for background processes.  It doesn't work with "&" instead.

```
$uninstallstring = '"echoargs" 1 2'
cmd /c $uninstall /s

Arg 0 is <1>
Arg 1 is <2>
Arg 2 is </s>


$uninstallstring = '"notepad" file.txt'
cmd /c $uninstall
```