# How to uninstall MSIs using the Uninstall Path

Tags: powershell, uninstallation, uninstallstring

I am trying to get the uninstall paths of a set of applications and uninstall them. So far i an get the list of uninstall paths. but i am struggling to actually uninstall the programs.

My code so far is.

```
    $app = @("msi1", "msi2", "msi3", "msi4")
     $Regpath = @(
                    'HKLM:\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Uninstall\*'
                    'HKLM:\Software\Wow6432Node\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Uninstall\*'
                )
                   
    foreach ($apps in $app){
    $UninstallPath = Get-ItemProperty $Regpath | where {$_.displayname -like "*$apps*"} | Select-Object -Property UninstallString
    
    $UninstallPath.UninstallString
    #Invoke-Expression UninstallPath.UninstallString
    #start-process "msiexec.exe" -arg "X $UnistallPath /qb" - wait
    }
```

this will return the following results:

```
    MsiExec.exe /X{F17025FB-0401-47C9-9E34-267FBC619AAE}
    MsiExec.exe /X{20DC0ED0-EA01-44AB-A922-BD9932AC5F2C}
    MsiExec.exe /X{29376A2B-2D9A-43DB-A28D-EF5C02722AD9}
    MsiExec.exe /X{18C9B6D0-DCDC-44D8-9294-0ED24B080F0C}
```

Im struggling to find away to execute these uninstall paths and actually uninstall the MSIs.

I have tried to use `Invoke-Expression $UninstallPath.UninstallString` but it just displays the windows installer and gives me the option for msiexec.

I have also tried to use `start-process "msiexec.exe" -arg "X $UnistallPath /qb" - wait`  however this gives the same issue.

Comment: `& cmd /c $UninstallPath.UninstallString /norestart`. Programs sometimes allow you to uninstall silently, all you need to do is ensure the key has `.QuietUninstallString` property. You can also google some of the switches for the specific product but, the invocation operator (`&`) should do the trick for you in regards to your question.

Comment: Thank you,  for this case a silent uninstall is not needed so I'm not worried about it being silent and the product is not regularly available so googling for switches was out of the question.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Note:

- This answer addresses the question as asked.
- [js2010's helpful answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/68383173/45375) shows a much more convenient alternative that avoids the original problem, via the [`PackageManagement`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/packagemanagement/?view=powershell-7) module's `Get-Package` and **`Uninstall-Package`** cmdlets. `Uninstall-Package` **supports uninstalling MSI-installed software (`-ProviderName msi`)**, but seemingly *not* "programs" (`-ProviderName Programs`); I'm unclear on whether uninstallation of *Windows Update* packages (`-ProviderName msu`) is supported.
  Note, however, that these providers are **only (directly) available in *Windows PowerShell***<sup>[1]</sup> - by contrast, [*PowerShell (Core)*](https://github.com/PowerShell/PowerShell/blob/master/README.md) as of v7.3.3 lacks these package providers altogether, and it's unclear (to me) whether they will ever be added.

---

**Problem:**

- The **uninstallation command lines stored in the `UninstallString` / `QuietUninstallString` registry values<sup>[2]</sup> are designed for *no-shell* / from-*`cmd.exe`* invocations**.<sup>[3]</sup>
- They therefore **can *fail* from PowerShell** if you pass them to [`Invoke-Expression`](https://learn.microsoft.com/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/invoke-expression), namely if they contain *unquoted* characters that have no special meaning outside shells / to `cmd.exe`, but are *metacharacters* in PowerShell, which applies to `{` and `}` in your case.

**Solutions**:

You have two options:

- **(a)** Simply pass the uninstallation string as-is to **`cmd /c`**

  - Note that - unlike when you call `msiexec.exe` directly from PowerShell or directly from `cmd.exe` - calling via `cmd /c` results in *synchronous* execution of `msiexec`, which is desirable.
- **(b)** Split the uninstallation string into executable and argument list, which allows you to call the command via **[`Start-Process`](https://learn.microsoft.com/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.management/start-process)**, which can give you more control over the invocation.

  - Be sure to use the `-Wait` switch to ensure that the installation completes before your script continues.

Note:

- The following commands assume that the uninstall string is contained in variable `$UninstallString` (the equivalent of `$UninstallPath.UninstallString` in your code):
- Situationally *appending options* to the command line isn't as straightforward as just appending, say, `' /quiet /norestart'`, because that won't work if the command line is merely an *unquoted executable path without spaces*, e.g., `C:\Program Files\WinRAR\uninstall.exe` - see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/64072309/45375) for a solution.

**Implementation of (a):**

```bash
# Simply pass the uninstallation string (command line) to cmd.exe
# via `cmd /c`. 
# Execution is synchronous (blocks until the command finishes).
cmd /c $UninstallString

$exitCode = $LASTEXITCODE
```

The [automatic `$LASTEXITCODE` variable](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Automatic_Variables#lastexitcode) can then be queried for the command line's *exit code*.

**Implementation of (b):**

```bash
# Split the command line into executable and argument list.
# Account for the fact that the executable name may be double-quoted.
if ($UninstallString[0] -eq '"') {
    $unused, $exe, $argList = $UninstallString -split '"', 3
}
else {
    $exe, $argList = $UninstallString -split ' ', 2
}

# Use Start-Process with -Wait to wait for the command to finish.
# -PassThru returns an object representing the process launched,
# whose .ExitCode property can then be queried.
$ps = if ($argList) {
        Start-Process -Wait -PassThru $exe $argList
      } else {
        Start-Process -Wait -PassThru $exe 
      }
$exitCode = $ps.ExitCode
```

You could also add `-NoNewWindow` to prevent *console* program-based uninstallation command lines from running in a new console window, but note that the only way to capture their stdout / stderr output via `Start-Process` is to redirect them to *files*, using the `-RedirectStandardOutput` / `-RedirectStandardError` parameters.

---

**Edition-specific / future improvements:**

The `Start-Process`-based method is cumbersome for two reasons:

- You cannot pass *whole command lines* and must instead specify the executable and arguments separately.

  - [GitHub proposal #14347](https://github.com/PowerShell/PowerShell/issues/14347) aims to add support for passing whole command lines.
- In *Windows PowerShell* (whose latest and *final* version is 5.1) you cannot pass an *empty* string or array to the (positionally implied) `-ArgumentList` parameter (hence the need for two separate calls above).

  - This problem has been fixed in the cross-platform, install-on-demand [*PowerShell (Core)*](https://github.com/PowerShell/PowerShell/blob/master/README.md) edition (versions 6 and above).

---

<sup>[1] If you don't mind the extra overhead, you can (temporarily) import the Windows PowerShell `PackageManagement` module even from PowerShell (Core), using the [Windows PowerShell compatibility feature](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Windows_PowerShell_Compatibility):

`Import-Module -UseWindowsPowerShell PackageManagement`.</sup>

<sup>[2] As shown in your question, they are stored in the `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Uninstall` (64-bit applications) and `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\Wow6432Node \Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Uninstall` (32-bit applications) registry keys, and possibly also - for *user-specific* installations - in their `HKEY_CURRENT_USER` counterparts; given that `HKEY_CURRENT_USER` only refers to the *current* user, looking for *other* users' user-specific installations would require more work.</sup>

<sup>[3] Hypothetically, it is possible to author valid no-shell command lines that *break* when called from `cmd.exe` (e.g. `foo.exe a&b` or `foo.exe "A \"B & C\ D"`), but that rarely, if ever, happens in practice.</sup>

Comment: Thank you, this explains why i was getting error constantly.   after a small break i managed to it working working using the following.  `$unin = $UninstallPath.UninstallString -Replace "msiexec.exe","" -Replace "/I","" -Replace "/X",""  
 $unin = $unin.Trim()  start-process "msiexec.exe" -arg "/X $unin /qb" -Wait`

Comment: Glad to hear it, @Dave. Note that the implementation of (b) above should work generally with _all_ uninstallation strings (unless you need to modify the arguments).

Answer (score 3):

Or for example:

```
get-package *chrome* | uninstall-package
```

Comment: Nicely done - I didn't know that `Uninstall-Package` also supports uninstalling _applications_. The caveat is that this only works in _Windows PowerShell_.

Comment: @mklement0 Will they ever support that again in ps 7?

Comment: It's a good question, and I don't know the answer, but see footnote [1] in my answer for a(n expensive) workaround.

Comment: Thank you for this, I will keep this in mind for later usage when we upgrade to a version that uses the Package Management module.

Comment: @dave You don't have 5.1?

Comment: Not at the time of writing, I'll be updating soon.