# Unable to remotely uninstall Google Chrome using registry key without manual acceptance

Tags: powershell, uninstallation, unattended-processing, uninstallstring

1. Get-Package "Google Chrome" | % { & ($_.Meta.Attributes["UninstallString"] -replace '"') /S

This command uninstalls other software except Google chrome , provider is programs. I have tried many things but this does not work.
Please help

Comment: What do you mean by, "*without manual acceptance*"? Do you mean silently? I believe you're calling the wrong string. Most programs will have a *quietuninstallstring*.

Comment: Good points, @AbrahamZinala, though I wouldn't say that _most_ have a `QuietUninstallString`; I'd say that not only _some_ even have an `UninstallString`, and among those only some have a `QuietUninstallString`. Swati is trying to achieve silent uninstallation with `/S`, but the command wouldn't work syntactically - and, above all, it seems that (a) Google Chrome doesn't even have an `UninstallString` value, and (b) piping to `Uninstall-Package` instead is a much simpler way to uninstall.

Comment: Uninstall-package is not working for programs based provider. It only works for MSI based softwares.

Comment: In registry key there uninstall string of Google Chrome, I tried invoke-expression as well but that also gives error for missing positional parameter for acceptance.

Comment: This command works , only thing is , i want to push this command remotely where it should not ask " Are you sure you want to uninstall Google Chrome , prompts for input Uninstall and Cancel". I am looking for unattended uninstallation where , where it accepts automatically for uninstallation . Can you also help me with invoke-expression , how to use command and arguments  , The uninstall string that is supposed to be used is  ---    "C:\Program Files\Google\Chrome\Application\92.0.4515.107\Installer\setup.exe" --uninstall --channel=stable --system-level --verbose-logging

Answer (score 4):

You say that your **Google Chrome installation** was performed **via the `Programs` package-management provider**, rather than via the `msi` provider (for the latter, see the bottom section).

Assuming that `$_.Meta.Attributes["UninstallString"]` has a value, it contains a string that contains a no-shell / for-`cmd.exe` *command line*, which often will *not* work when executed directly from PowerShell with [`Invoke-Expression`](https://learn.microsoft.com/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/invoke-expression), because PowerShell has more metacharacters than `cmd.exe` that require *quoting*, notably `{` and `}`, as used in GUIDs.

- More fundamentally, **`&`, the [call operator](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Operators#call-operator-) does *not* support executing whole command lines**, it expects only the name or path of a command or executable, optionally followed by arguments.

In the simplest case, you can do the following:

```sh
Get-Package 'Google Chrome' | % { 
  cmd /c ($_.Meta.Attributes['UninstallString'] + ' /S')
}
```

For more information, see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/68382753/45375).

---

**IF your Google Chrome was installed via the *`msi`* package provider** (verify with: `(Get-Package 'Google Chrome').ProviderName`):

Not all installed programs have an `UninstallString` attribute (and even fewer have a `QuietUninstallString` one), and an `msi`-provider-installed Google Chrome doesn't have one.

However, you should be able to pipe to [`Uninstall-Package`](https://learn.microsoft.com/powershell/module/packagemanagement/uninstall-package) for silent (unattended) uninstallation:

```sh
Get-Package 'Google Chrome' | Uninstall-Package
```