# How can I finish this PowerShell script?

Tags: windows, powershell

I've been tasked to uninstall "Rhino 6" from all Windows 10 computers.  If I run:

```sh
gci "HKLM:\SOFTWARE\Wow6432Node\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Uninstall" | foreach { gp $_.PSPath } | ? { $_ -match "Rhino 6" } | select UninstallString
```

Then I get a very useful:

```sh
UninstallString
---------------
"C:\ProgramData\Package Cache\{680b3429-6aab-4318-a4e1-74347755c79d}\Bootstrapper.exe"  /uninstall
```

So, I wrote this:

```sh
Start-Process "C:\ProgramData\Package Cache\{75519ff1-80d4-4471-96c0-970328e182f1}\Bootstrapper.exe" -ArgumentList "/uninstall -quiet"
```

Which works great, except that there are MANY versions of "Rhino 6" and they each spit out a different uninstall string.

How can I make a script that does the first command and then uses the path from the answer in the second command without all of the other stuff that gets spit out?

Comment: If you're looking for a general way to invoke a command line stored in an `UninstallString` registry value, see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/68382753/45375).

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to uninstall MSIs using the Uninstall Path](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68382074/how-to-uninstall-msis-using-the-uninstall-path)

Comment: I don't see the answer to my question in that post.  I'm asking how to strip away the "UninstallString
---------------" portion of the output so that I can use it as a variable.

Answer (score 0):

Something like this should work. Assign the output of your get child item (gci) then foreach loop to access the value that is assigned to $rhino.UninstallString

```
#HashTable
$rhino = gci "HKLM:\SOFTWARE\Wow6432Node\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Uninstall" | foreach { gp $_.PSPath } | ? { $_ -match "Rhino 6" } | Select UninstallString
#Output of $rhino: @{UninstallString=C:\somepath\some.exe}@{UninstallString=C:\someotherpath\some.exe}

#Loop through assigning each to $uninstall and use $uninstall.UninstallString to start-process
foreach ($uninstall in $rhino) {
    Start-Process $uninstall.UninstallString -ArgumentList "/uninstall -quiet"
}
```

Comment: Hi this doesn't work because the output from $rhino has a bunch of additional text, namely: UninstallString
---------------

Comment: The uninstallstring ---- won't be assigned to the $rhino var. You can validate this by doing 'write-host $rhino'

Comment: See this [example](https://imgur.com/a/ipHEew5)

Note this is missing from the outputs
`UninstallString
-----------------`

Comment: The gci command you run above without assigning it to a variable `$rhino` will simply output the table. More information on the default output of cmdlets can be found [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/scripting/samples/using-format-commands-to-change-output-view?view=powershell-7.2)

Comment: Weird that it didn't work in testing.  I'll have to play with this.  Thank you.