# Uninstall program using get-process and uninstallstring with call operator (&)

Tags: powershell, uninstallation, uninstallstring

I'm trying create a uninstall script to uninstall any program tha I want.

I was using this script:

get-package -Name "*XXXXX*" | Uninstall-Package

But I saw that when the "provideName" attribut is "Program" it not working, so I use this.

```
$packageArray = get-package "*XXXX*"
foreach ($package in $packageArray){
$a = $package.ProviderName
if ($a -eq "Programs"){
& {($package.Meta.Attributes["UninstallString"]  -replace '"') /S}
}
if ($a -ne "Programs"){
get-package -Name "*XXXXX*" | Uninstall-Package
}
}
```

This part bellow was working fine when I have not ""&quot."", like this.

& {($package.Meta.Attributes["UninstallString"]  -replace '"') /S}

Print:
[image]

But now I'm getting erro when a uninstall string has "&quot." value, like this.

UninstallString=""&quot";C:\Users\rsantanna\AppData\Local\GoToMeeting\19950\G2MUninstall.exe" /uninstall"

Print.
[image: Example of ""&quot."" value]

When it occur I get this error.

& : The term 'C:\Users\rsantanna\AppData\Local\GoToMeeting\19950\G2MUninstall.exe /uninstall' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet, function, script file, or operable program. Check the spelling of the name, or if a path was included, verify that the
path is correct and try again.
At line:6 char:7

- ```
  & ($UninstallString)
  ```
- ```
    ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
  ```

  - CategoryInfo          : ObjectNotFound: (C:\Users\rsanta....exe /uninstall:String) [], CommandNotFoundException
  - FullyQualifiedErrorId : CommandNotFoundException

Anyone can help me ?

Answer (score 1):

- You cannot *directly* execute a *string expression* such as `($package.Meta.Attributes["UninstallString"]  -replace '"')`
- While you *can* do so via `&`, the [call operator](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Operators#call-operator-), it only works if the string expression evaluates to a command *name* or *executable file path* only.

  - Notably, you can *not* use `&` to execute an entire *command line*, which is what `$package.Meta.Attributes["UninstallString"]` typically contains.
  - Note that your use of `&` is with a [*script block*](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Script_Blocks) (`{ ... }`), which allows you to execute arbitrary statements contained in the block; however, perhaps needless to say, these statements are subject to the usual syntax rules, and it is the one and only statement in your block that causes a syntax error (that is actually different from the error you report).

As explained in detail in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/68382753/45375), the command lines stored in `UninstallString` registry values are designed for invocation from `cmd.exe` or from *no-shell* environments.

Therefore, the simplest solution is to call via `cmd.exe /c`:

```
cmd.exe /c "$($package.Meta.Attributes["UninstallString"]) /S"
```

If your uninstall command line, as returned from `$package.Meta.Attributes["UninstallString"]`, really contains `&quot;` in lieu of *verbatim* `"` characters (double quotes) - which would be unusual - you'll need to replace the former with the latter first:

```
cmd.exe /c "$($package.Meta.Attributes["UninstallString"] -replace '&quot;', '"') /S"
```

It's unclear what command produced the `&quot;` output in your screenshot, but given that it shows the text of an *XML* document, the use of `&quot;` instead of `"` is simply a necessity for encoding literal  `"` chars.

Comment: Hi, thanks for helping. It work when I have no "&quot." value on "uninstallString", but when I have this it notwork and I recive the error "cmd.exe : 'C:\Program' is not recognized as an internal or external command,"

Comment: I added prints in my questions, if you could, please check it.

Comment: @RafaelSant'Anna, are you saying that the uninstall string _literally_ contains `&quot;` instead of `"`? It's unclear where your XML-based printout comes from. Normally, `$package.Meta.Attributes["UninstallString"]` contains values with _literal_ `"` embedded in them, if needed. In that event, the `cmd /c` call should succeed. If the `&quot;` values are really present in  what `$package.Meta.Attributes["UninstallString"]` returns, add `-replace '&quot;', '"'` before the closing `)` inside `$(...)`.

Comment: Perfect. It works. I don't know why I did not think it before. Loks my script.  $program = "*XXX*"
    $packageArray = get-package $program
    foreach ($package in $packageArray){
    $a = $package.ProviderName
    if ($a -eq "Programs"){
    cmd /c ($package.Meta.Attributes["UninstallString"] -replace '&quot;' -replace '"') 
    }
    if ($a -ne "Programs"){
    get-package -Name $program | Uninstall-Package
    }
    }