# How to uninstall Chrome with PS script

Tags: powershell, google-chrome, uninstallation, regedit

I am writing a script that uninstall Chrome and install specific version of this. I want to keep short this code but Invoke-Expression or Invoke-Command not working properly because the uninstall strings. How can write as short as possible?

```
$Uninstall = 
'HKCU:\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Uninstall\*',
'HKLM:\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Uninstall\*',
'HKLM:\SOFTWARE\WOW6432Node\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Uninstall\*' | ForEach-Object {
    Get-ItemProperty $_ | Where-Object {
        $_.DisplayName -eq 'Google Chrome'
    } | Select-Object -ExpandProperty 'UninstallString' | Invoke-Expression
}
```

Uninstall string: `"C:\Program Files\Google\Chrome\Application\117.0.5938.92\Installer\setup.exe" --uninstall --channel=stable --system-level --verbose-logging`

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How can I uninstall an application using PowerShell?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/113542/how-can-i-uninstall-an-application-using-powershell)

Comment: Not exactly but it can be different way for me. ^^

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The simplest solution is to pass the uninstallation command line to `cmd /c`:

```bash
$Uninstall = 
  'HKCU:\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Uninstall\*',
  'HKLM:\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Uninstall\*',
  'HKLM:\SOFTWARE\WOW6432Node\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Uninstall\*' | 
      Get-ItemProperty | 
      Where-Object {
        $_.DisplayName -eq 'Google Chrome'
      } | 
      ForEach-Object {
        cmd /c $_.UninstallString
      }
```

The problem with trying to use [`Invoke-Expression`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/invoke-expression) is that it assumes *PowerShell* syntax, whereas the `UninstallString` strings assume *no-shell* syntax, which - except in edge cases - also works from `cmd.exe`.

For alternatives and additional information, see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/68382753/45375).

Comment: I had to wait uninstallation then I added this line. Is it proper way? Start-Process -FilePath "$env:ComSpec" -ArgumentList "/c $Uninstall" -WindowStyle Hidden -Wait