Powershell Script not removing Chrome when code says too
In my powershell code it is tasked to remove google crhome. The code compiles however it states Google Chrome is not installed on the PC. However Google Chome is installed on the PC. I dont understand why it is not being reconginized. Any idea what to do next?
# Define the application name
$appName = "Google Chrome"

# Get the application details from the registry
$app = Get-WmiObject -Query "SELECT * FROM Win32_Product WHERE Name = '$appName'"

if ($app) {
    Write-Output "Uninstalling $appName..."

    # Uninstall the application
    $app.Uninstall() | Out-Null

    if ($?) {
        Write-Output "$appName has been successfully uninstalled."
    } else {
        Write-Output "Failed to uninstall $appName."
    }
} else {
    Write-Output "$appName is not installed on this machine."
}


Try a rather robust approach by a straightforward querying to the registry for the installed MSI-based applications, particularly those registered under the MSI installer path.

The Win32_Product WMI class is best avoided, because it returns only Windows Installer-installed applications, is not query-optimized (even when filtering, all products must be enumerated), and - most importantly - invariably performs consistency checks and potentially triggers repair actions.  A registry-based alternative is in https://stackoverflow.com/a/77207095/45375, one based on the PackageManagement module in https://stackoverflow.com/a/68383173/45375 (Windows PowerShell only).

Maybe the name is a little different, try to display all apps that are like „chrome“ first to see what ur dealing with :
$var = Get-WmiObject win32_product | ? {$_.name -like '*chrome*'); $var


I did that and printed the var it does print Google Chrome, but it does not uninstall it.

Ok, now replace your „$app = Get-WmiObject -Query….“ with this one and run it. At least the response must be different from the original „"$appName is not installed on this machine."
Since $app is.
