# Issue with path not being treated as encapsulated when calling cmd /C

Tags: powershell

I'm having an issue where it seems my encapsulated path is not being treated as encapsulted. I have tried a few different things, to no avail. I'm wondering if anyone has seen this before?

```
Function Remove-App-EXE-SILENT-QUOTES([String]$appName)
{
    $appCheck = Get-ChildItem -Path HKLM:\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Uninstall, HKLM:\SOFTWARE\Wow6432Node\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Uninstall | Get-ItemProperty | Where-Object {$_.DisplayName -eq $appName } | Select-Object -Property DisplayName,UninstallString
    if($appCheck -ne $null){
        Write-host "Uninstalling "$appCheck.DisplayName
        $uninst="`"" + ($appCheck.UninstallString) + "`""
        Write-Host $uninst
        cmd /C $uninst
    }
    else{
        Write-Host "$appName is not installed on this computer"
    }
}
Remove-App-EXE-SILENT-QUOTES "DELLOSD"
```

output is

```
PS C:\Program Files> C:\Users\HOL-OP05\Documents\RemoveDellOSD.ps1
Uninstalling  DELLOSD
"C:\Program Files (x86)\InstallShield Installation Information\{50033799-D5D3-4759-9ABD-589AD04F33C1}\setup.exe -runfromtemp -l0x0009 -removeonly"
cmd : 'C:\Program' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
At C:\Users\HOL-OP05\Documents\RemoveDellOSD.ps1:8 char:9
+         cmd /C $uninst
+         ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: ('C:\Program' is...ternal command,:String) [], RemoteException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : NativeCommandError
 
operable program or batch file.
```

Comment: Tried, it's ignored for some reason. Isn't called at all

Comment: Just tried it. Same issue. and the uninstall string does call the uninstallation. I've grabbed it straight from the reg and it has -removeonly and if I call it it does start uninstalling

Comment: `"C:\Program Files (x86)\InstallShield Installation Information\{50033799-D5D3-4759-9ABD-589AD04F33C1}\setup.exe -runfromtemp -l0x0009 -removeonly"` is not correct, even from cmd/batch. It should read as `"C:\Program Files (x86)\InstallShield Installation Information\{50033799-D5D3-4759-9ABD-589AD04F33C1}\setup.exe" -runfromtemp -l0x0009 -removeonly`. It is you who appears to be adding the doublequotes yourself, so put those in the correct location in the string.

Comment: It seems like you want to uninstall a particular app. If you actually happen to know the uninstall string why don't you just run the uninstall command using its proper path?  ... without all the fuss about reading the string from the registry ...

Comment: compo ty. I *thought* i tried that but i guess I didn't

Comment: I tried to make a general answer for uninstallstrings with quotes in them.  This assumes the exe is properly quoted.  https://stackoverflow.com/a/64073143/6654942

Comment: @js2010, that wouldn't work in the case at hand, because the uninstall command line is _malformed_ (lacks the embedded quoting around the executable path with spaces); your technique would identify `C:\Program` as the executable path, just like `cmd.exe` itself via `/C`. You need to fix the command line first, as shown below.

Comment: P.S., @2010: If a given uninstall command line is well-formed, it's much simpler to pass it as-is to `cmd /c`; your linked answer deals with a special use case where the intent is to _add options_ to an uninstall command line.

Comment: @mklement0 cmd /c, I like it.  Plus it waits for background processes.

Comment: @mklement0 for that matter `powershell "command" options`, but that doesn't wait for background processes.

Comment: @js2010, `cmd /c` only waits for the immediate child process (unlike `Start-Process -Wait`), but - unlike PowerShell in direct execution - also does so for _GUI_-subsystem applications, such as `msiexec.exe`. `powershell "command" options` breaks if `"command"` contains a quoted executable path (or an unquoted one that contains spaces), because you need `&` to execute such paths. Uninstall command-line strings are written for execution from `cmd.exe` / in no-shell contexts and can break PowerShell's syntax, so the easiest solution is to defer to `cmd.exe` via `/c`

Answer (score 1):

- Your attempt to enclose `$appCheck.UninstallString` in *embedded* `"..."` is unnecessary (and happens to make no difference in this case)
- PowerShell, when it constructs the process command line ultimately used behind the scenes, will *automatically* enclose the value of `$appCheck.UninstallString` in `"..."`, if that value contains *spaces*<sup>[1]</sup>, such as in the case at hand.
- Therefore, it should *normally* be enough to invoke the uninstallation command string as follows:

  ```bash
   # Works, but only with well-formed uninstallation command strings.
   cmd /C $appCheck.UninstallString
  ```
- As [Compo](https://stackoverflow.com/users/6738015/compo) points out, your uninstallation command string is *malformed*: For it to work as intended when interpreted by `cmd.exe`, the path of the executable inside the command must be *enclosed in embedded `"..."`*, because it *contains spaces*; that is, the *verbatim content* of `$appCheck.UninstallString` would have to be (note how only the `setup.exe` file path is enclosed in `"..."`):

  ```bash
  "C:\Program Files (x86)\InstallShield Installation Information\{50033799-D5D3-4759-9ABD-589AD04F33C1}\setup.exe" -runfromtemp -l0x0009 -removeonly
  ```
- In other words: The **root cause** is that **whatever installation application created the `UninstallString` registry value** in key `HKLM:\SOFTWARE\Wow6432Node\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Uninstall` on installation **did so in a broken manner** - see below for a potential workaround.

---

An **automated workaround** workaround for such broken `UninstallString` strings is possible, *assuming that the executable path in the string explicitly uses the `.exe` filename extension*:

```bash
# Add missing double quotes around an embedded executable path with spaces.
$uninst = $appCheck.UninstallString -replace '^([^"].+? .+?\.exe)(?!$)', '"$1"'
# ...
cmd /C $uninst
```

- The above adds missing double quotes around an embedded executable path with spaces, and leaves already well-formed command-line strings alone.
- This is achieved via the [regex](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Regular_Expressions)-based [`-replace`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Comparison_Operators#replacement-operator) operator.

  - For an explanation of the regex and the option to experiment with it, see [this regex101.com page](https://regex101.com/r/F0gGhz/1).

Here is self-contained sample code:

```bash
# Sample uninstall command-line strings.
$uninstallCommandLines = @(
  # !! BROKEN
  'C:\Program Files (x86)\InstallShield Installation Information\{50033799-D5D3-4759-9ABD-589AD04F33C1}\setup.exe -runfromtemp -l0x0009 -removeonly'
  # OK, because there is only an executable path, no arguments.
  'C:\Program Files (x86)\Some Directory\Foo.exe'
  # OK, because the executable path contains no spalces.
  'C:\SomePath\WithoutSpaces\Bar.exe -baz'
  # OK, because the executable path with spaces is already double-quoted.
  '"C:\Some Path\With Spaces\Qux.exe" -quux'
)

# Process each and fix on demand.
$uninstallCommandLines | ForEach-Object {
  $original = $_
  # Fix it, if necessary; the result can be used with cmd /C
  $fixed = $original -replace '^([^"].+? .+?\.exe)(?!$)', '"$1"'
  [pscustomobject] @{
    Original = $original
    PotentiallyFixed = $fixed
    ActuallyFixed = $original -ne $fixed
  }
} | Format-List
```

Output:

```
Original         : C:\Program Files (x86)\InstallShield Installation Information\{50033799-D5D3-4759-9ABD-589AD04F33C1}\setup.exe -runfromtemp -l0x0009 -removeonly
PotentiallyFixed : "C:\Program Files (x86)\InstallShield Installation Information\{50033799-D5D3-4759-9ABD-589AD04F33C1}\setup.exe" -runfromtemp -l0x0009 -removeonly
ActuallyFixed    : True

Original         : C:\Program Files (x86)\Some Directory\Foo.exe
PotentiallyFixed : C:\Program Files (x86)\Some Directory\Foo.exe
ActuallyFixed    : False

Original         : C:\SomePath\WithoutSpaces\Bar.exe -baz
PotentiallyFixed : C:\SomePath\WithoutSpaces\Bar.exe -baz
ActuallyFixed    : False

Original         : "C:\Some Path\With Spaces\Qux.exe" -quux
PotentiallyFixed : "C:\Some Path\With Spaces\Qux.exe" -quux
ActuallyFixed    : False
```

---

<sup>[1] It actually neglects to *escape* `"` characters that are *embedded* in such a value, but that is where broken worlds meet: `cmd /c` actually requires there to be *no* escaping. When targeting *other* console applications, however, PowerShell's broken behavior continues to cause problems in *Windows PowerShell* and caused problems in [*PowerShell (Core) 7*](https://github.com/PowerShell/PowerShell/blob/master/README.md) *up to v7.2.x* - see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/74440425/45375) for background information.</sup>